# Problems with Json Serialize Dictionary<Enum, Int32>

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dictionary

whenever i try to serialize the dictionary i get the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Type 
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Foo.DictionarySerializationTest+TestEnum, Foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary,
keys must be strings or object
```

My Testcase is:

```
public class DictionarySerializationTest
{
  public enum TestEnum { A, B, C }
  //tried with numbers, too: public enum TestEnum { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 }

  public void SerializationTest()
  {
    Dictionary<TestEnum, Int32> data = new Dictionary<TestEnum, Int32>();

    data.Add(TestEnum.A, 1);
    data.Add(TestEnum.B, 2);
    data.Add(TestEnum.C, 3);

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    String result = serializer.Serialize(data);
    // Throws
  }

  public void SerializationToObjectTest()
  {
    Dictionary<object, Int32> data = new Dictionary<object, Int32>();

    data.Add(Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.A), 1);
    data.Add(Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.B), 2);
    data.Add(Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.C), 3);

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    String result = serializer.Serialize(data);
    // Throws
  }

  public void SerializationStringTest()
  {
    Dictionary<String, Int32> data = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();

    data.Add(TestEnum.A.ToString(), 1);
    data.Add(TestEnum.B.ToString(), 2);
    data.Add(TestEnum.C.ToString(), 3);

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    String result = serializer.Serialize(data);
    // Succeeds
  }

}
```

Of course i could use .ToString() whenever i enter something into the Dictionary but since it's used quite often in performance relevant methods i would prefer using the enum.

My only solution is using .ToString() and converting before entering the performance critical regions but that is clumsy and i would have to change my code structure just to be able to serialize the data.

Does anyone have an idea how i could serialize the dictionary as `<Enum, Int32>`?

I use the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer for serialization.

**UPDATE:**

I switched to `Dictionary<String, Int32>` now and it works but i hope someone shows a solution as i don't really like using strings in place of a type safe enum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know it's late, but maybe someone else can make use of it in the future. You can achieve what you need using LINQ:

```
Dictionary<TestEnum, Int32> data = new Dictionary<TestEnum, Int32>();

data.Add(TestEnum.A, 1);
data.Add(TestEnum.B, 2);
data.Add(TestEnum.C, 3);

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, Int32> dataToSerialize = data.Keys.ToDictionary(p => p.ToString(), p => data[p]);
string dataSerialized = serializer.Serialize(dataToSerialize);
```

Comment: Not too late... Still helpful in 2016

Comment: I would still recommend using Json.NET as it states in the JavaScriptSerializer class documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Use Newtonsoft (Newtonsoft.Json.dll) to serialize the Dictionary object and you'd be fine. It's a popular third party library you would have to download and include in your project as a reference.

See example below:

```
var _validationInfos = new Dictionary<ImportField, ValidationInfo>();
var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_validationInfos);
```

Comment: These days, even Microsoft recommends using the Newtonsoft JSON library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are having trouble because `TestEnum` is declared as a `private enum`.  Try marking it as a `public enum`.  The serializer needs to be able to find your enum via reflection in order to serialize it.

Also according to the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), the enums must have integer values. So you might want to write:

```
public enum TestEnum { A = 1, B = 2, C =3 }
```

Also, the docs say that this enum will just get mapped to its corresponding integer value during the serialization.  So depending on what you are doing on the other end, `String`s might be more expressive and easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing the enum to public and adding integer values didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Exception says "keys must be strings or object" so try

```
data.Add(Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.A));
data.Add(Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.B));
data.Add(Enum.ToObject(typeof(TestEnum), TestEnum.C));
```

I did not test it though, just a guess.

Comment: It doesn't seem to accept all object types, the error is still the same. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve created JavaScriptSerializer extension DeserializeDictionary- see http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2011/06/03/javascriptserializer-extension-deserializedictionarytkey-tvalue.aspx

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue>  DeserializeDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this JavaScriptSerializer jss, string jsonText)
{
    var dictWithStringKey = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,TValue>>(jsonText);
    var dict=dictWithStringKey.ToDictionary(de => jss.ConvertToType<TKey>(de.Key),de => de.Value);
        return dict;
}
```