# Alternative to Dictionary with enum keys?

Tags: c#, .net

In my solution i depend heavily on Dictionaries with an enum as a key. I find it is easy to understand and to read this construction.

One significant obstacle to the above is that it is not possible to serialize this. See [Problems with Json Serialize Dictionary<Enum, Int32>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892910/problems-with-json-serialize-dictionaryenum-int32) for more info on this.

My question is:
Is there a equally readable and intuitive pattern for replacing the `Dictionary<enunm,object>`  that is json serializable with the built in json serializer?

Today I have replaced `a.Instance.QueryableFields[Fields.Title]` with `a.Instance.QueryableFields[ Fields.Title.ToString()]` . Not very elegant, and it is opening up for errors.

Comment: Is the enum a property on your object being stored as the value of the dictionary? I might suggest using the enum value as a hash code in that case.

Comment: How would that work? Could you point me to an example?

Answer (score 1):

When serializing it, just select the string value. It's not very neat, but it works.

```
a.Instance.QueryableFields.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString(), x => x.Value)
```

Comment: It is an option i have cosidered. But then i have to write my own serialize method.  Thank you for the suggestion, but i am looking for a way to replace the entire thing. Either the dictionary or the enum.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily replace a dictionary with an array here, as in C# Enums are internally saved as integers:

```
public enum MyEnum { Zero=0, One, Two };

object[] dictionary = new object[3];
dictionary[(int)MyEnum.Zero] = 4;
```

EDIT: (see comments)

You can also replace `Dictionary<Enum, Object>` with `Dictionary<Int, Object>`.

Comment: This has sense only if you're sure that values go from `0` to `array.Length-1` without any break. If you have an enum like `{A=0, B=42, C=31415}` you should create an array of `31416` elements...